# Limiting the content of TextField in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a blog index page where all the blog post entries are shown. But i want to limit the content of the post body to certain amount (Similar to any blog you see on the internet) so not all the content is visible but when user click on **Read More** link he can see that particular post in details.

I know how to create page for single article but i am not able to figure out how to limit the post body content. Do i need to change anything in the model or i can do this directly from templates

```
<h1><a href="/blog/{{ post.slug }}/">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
<p>{{ post.post_body }}</p>
<a href="/blog/{{ post.slug }}/" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
```

I have declared post body as textfield

```
post_body = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
truncatechars¶
```

Truncates a string if it is longer than the specified number of characters. Truncated strings will end with a translatable ellipsis sequence (”...”).

Argument: Number of characters to truncate to

For example:

{{ value|truncatechars:9 }}
If value is "Joel is a slug", the output will be "Joel i...".

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: this gives ... (dots) at the end is it possible to now show those dots

Comment: you can rewrite this template tag, create templatetags.py and write your own template tag  and use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use Built-in Template tag "truncatewords", like this below:

{{ post.post_body | truncatewords:50 }}

This will show the first 50 words of your post.

Here is the [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords)